# RDP Error: Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end. Please try connecting to the remote computer again."

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

i have setup a windows 11 vm on my proxmox root server hosted by hetzner and i m trying to connect to it via rdp. i have setup port forwarding of the linux host using iptables. the connection is fine and works flawlessly when doing some light work (using word, looking stuff up on the internet etc).

but after a few minutes of usage or when stressing out the network a bit too much (eg. by watching a youtube video) i get the following error message and my remote connection ends:

"Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end. Please try connecting to the remote computer again."

i have read online that this might be caused by some sort of timing problems (local and remote clocks out of sync), so i already made sure that both local and remote got the same time, but this didnt help.

can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this issue?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Read [this post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/367256-rdp-suddenly-plagued-with-because-of-an-error-in-data-encryption) and try the solutions that worked for some users. Let me know if one of them has solved the problem.

Comment: thanks! i ll try it out and update the post accordingly if i find a solution :)

Comment: it seems to be working now! i tried a bunch of thinks like 'Local Area Connection -> Properties -> Configure -> Advanced -> IPv4 Large Send Offload =Disabled.' and flushing the network settings. thanks @harrymc, i would like to mark your comment as the correct answer or at least upvote, sadly its not possible with comments :/

Comment: I'll put up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post
[RDP: Suddenly plagued with "Because of an error in data encryption..."](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/367256-rdp-suddenly-plagued-with-because-of-an-error-in-data-encryption)
deals with this problem and has several workarounds suggested by users.

The one that seems to have worked for the poster is that of :

- Run *Settings > Network & Internet > Change adapter options*
- Right-click your network adapter and select Properties
- Click Configure
- Click Advanced
- Click "Large Send Offload (IPv4)"
- Set to Disabled
- Click OK
- Reboot might be required.

If the above doesn't work for someone, there are more workarounds
inside the above link.

Comment: Someone forgot to upvote.. anywho, for me the "suddenly" was a changed VM host after moving the guest with a different NIC (1GB->10GB). Guess that has widely different features. Also, the packages go through an IPSEC tunnel in my case.